# What is the oldest building in the world still in use?

Tags: where-on-earth, factoids, architecture, landmarks

What is the oldest building or structure in the world that's still in regular use today?

For the sake of the question, I'm not looking for something that still exists purely as a tourist attraction.  (Unless the building is closed to the public part time to allow it to serve its purpose.  ex: a church that's open to tourists, but still runs regular services.)

Comment: Would Stonehenge count?

Comment: Does the Great Wall of China still defend against Mongol hordes?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai it doesn't have to be the _original_ usage. It's still a great tourist attraction of China.

Comment: Maeshowe, maybe, or Skara Brae or the Ring of Brodgar. They predate Stonehenge by a fair bit and two of them are still used. Skara Brae is now just a tourist site.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai wiki says the great wall goes as far back as seven centuries BCE so why not make that an answer together with some sources? you'll have my +1

Answer (score 52):

This question is hard to answer since you would have to define "in use" very precisely. Here are some wild guesses:

- Wikipedia has [a list of the oldest buildings in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_oldest_buildings_in_the_world). Prominently feature tombs/graves/similar and you could well argue they are still in use. That would go back as far as very roughly 4000 B.C.
- [Stonehenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonehenge) is believed to have been constructed ca. 3000 - 2000 B.C. and still [a place of religious](http://metro.co.uk/2015/12/22/its-winter-solstice-so-druids-wiccans-and-pagans-are-having-a-banging-party-at-stonehenge-5579776/) significance for e.g. neopaganism.
- Parts of the [Great Stupa of Sanchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanchi) are from as early as 300 B.C. and the complex is still in use as a temple.
- The [Verona Arena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verona_Arena) is dated 30 A.D. and still used e.g. for concerts.

Further reading:

- [15 of the World's Oldest Buildings Still in Use Today](http://www.ba-bamail.com/content.aspx?emailid=18640)
- The same question on History SE: [Oldest building in the world still in use](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/oldest-building-in-the-world-still-in-use)

The accepted answer there is the [Pantheon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheon,_Rome) in Rome from 128 A.D. and still a church to day. However the most upvoted answer points to several arenas/theaters still in occasional use.

> The [Epidaurus Theatre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidaurus#Theatre) (ca. 300-340 BC), the [Delphi theatre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi) (4th century BC) and the [Odeon of Herodes Atticus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odeon_of_Herodes_Atticus) (161 AD) in the Acropolis of Athens (known locally as the the Herodeon), still fulfil their original purpose, all three are constantly used as venues for [various festivals](http://greekfestival.gr/en/venues). The ancient theatre in [Dion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dion,_Pieria) is also used occasionally.

Comment: There are other stone circles which are probably older than Stonehenge, and also used by neopagans. eg Calanais

Comment: Stonehenge is not "still" in use as a place of religious significance; that implies unbroken continuity between its ancient users and its modern ones, which does not exist. The structure was disused for a long time. The current religious use of Stonehenge is a very recent phenomenon with no direct connection to its ancient use.

Comment: @PaulLegato "Are you still eating that stuff?" "No, I've stopped for a week about a month ago"

Comment: @PaulLegato The OP never mentioned that the use of such building must not have stopped during the years... It has to be old and *right now* be used in some way.

Comment: Stonehenge isn't even the oldest stone circle in the UK (or the biggest, by any means) - not sure why it ends up in any lists...

Comment: @RoryAlsop I don't feel sufficiently qualified on that, would you mind editing my post regarding that (I +1d your comment to the Q) or post an own answer? I would appreciate that :)

Comment: @JanDvorak That is a misleading example. In most cases "still doing <something>" does have the connotation of having done that something throughout some span of time, framed by some distinct point in the past. If you met a childhood friend who played piano for a few years when you knew him and asked him, "Do you still play the piano?" an answer of "Yes I do." would certainly imply that he has been playing the piano since then. If he had given it up a few years after you last saw him and then took it up again, he would usually use a qualifier such as "Yeah, I've picked it up again."

Comment: @JanDvorak This is especially pertinent to the case of StoneHenge since there, given the timescales. It would be closer to your friend having played when he was 8 then giving up when he was 9, starting again at 30 and you meeting him when he's 31. Anyone answering "Yes I still play the piano," in this example would be very strange.

Comment: @DRF: re: continuous use or not: What really matters here is that both versions of the question are interesting, and I'd like to see answers for both.  "Still in use for the original purpose" rules out a lot of things that are basically only in use as tourist attractions / museums, which I think is a lot less interesting.  I'd also be interested in a list of buildings other than religious buildings and arenas.  i.e. are there any other kinds of buildings that have stood the test of time?

Comment: *"Prominently feature tombs/graves/similar and you could well argue they are still in use."* Glad I wasn't drinking my coffee when I read that.

Comment: @JanDvorak The "Are you still eating that stuff?" analogy doesn't really hold, since it isn't "you" at all.  Your great-great-great-etc-great-grandfather ate that stuff, and then no one in your family line did until you picked it up.  "Still" is really not an applicable word here.

Comment: One of the oldest but not the oldest: The [Alcántara Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alc%C3%A1ntara_Bridge) in Spain, built 104-106 A.D. Google Maps shows road EX-117 crossing it.

Answer (score 26):

The Great Pyramid of Giza initially had two functions, to serve as a tomb for the pharaoh, and to demonstrate his power and prestige. Today, it has two functions, to serve as a tourist attraction and to demonstrate the power and prestige of the pharaohs. It is a structure that has continuously fulfilled one of its functions since 2540 BC.

As far as I know, it is never closed to tourists to fulfill its status symbol function, but it makes quite a good status symbol even while open.

Comment: There are several older Pyramids that would probably be technically better answers, but the Pyramids certainly are not unreasonable answers in general for the reasons you state.

Comment: Wouldn't it serve three? Or is it no longer a tomb for the pharoh?

Comment: @mkingsbu The whereabouts of Khufu's mummy are currently unknown. If it is in the pyramid, it is well hidden.

Comment: @Joe I think the Great Pyramid is doing a better job of continued function as a status symbol than e.g. the Bent Pyramid.

Answer (score 20):

The [Theatre](http://www.epidavros.gr/en/odimos/taytotita-tis-epidavroy/to-theatro-tis-epidavrou.html) of [Epidaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidaurus) (4th century BCE!) still has [performances](http://greekfestival.gr/en/venues/view/ancient-theatre-of-epidaurus). It is not, however, an enclosed building.

Comment: And it is considered the top Theater in Greece. Back when things were more serious, it was the ultimate honor for an artist, to perform there.

Answer (score 15):

The [Etchmiadzin Cathedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etchmiadzin_Cathedral) was built in 301 AD.

> The original church was built in the early fourth century—between 301 and 303 according to tradition—by Armenia's patron saint Gregory the Illuminator, following the adoption of Christianity as a state religion by King Tiridates III. It replaced a preexisting temple, symbolizing the conversion from paganism to Christianity. The core of the current building was built in 483/4 by Vahan Mamikonian after the cathedral was severely damaged in a Persian invasion. From its foundation until the second half of the fifth century, Etchmiadzin was the seat of the Catholicos, the supreme head of the Armenian Church.

Answer (score 14):

I have prayed at the Western Wall of [The Temple Mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Mount) in Jerusalem. My ancestors have been [priests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohen) there since about the **10th century BC**.

[image]

Comment: The original temple mount does not exist.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow: The Western Wall where Jews today pray is a first-century BC extension to the original temple floorplan, which is still buried under the Temple Mount, still considered holy, and still in use by Jews today as that is the direction in which we pray.

Comment: The Temple Mount as an engineered structure rather than a natural feature only dates to about 19 BC with Herod's expansion.

Answer (score 5):

A lot depends on your definitions of "building", "use", and whether "use" is required to be continuous throughout history. A good candidate is the pantheon in Rome (AD 128). It was a place of pagan worship to start with, became a church when Rome became Christian, and has been in use as a church since then. Amphitheatres and pyramids don't really fit the "walls supporting a roof" definition of "building".

Comment: I intentionally didn't specify what I meant by building in the hopes of getting more diverse answers.

Answer (score 3):

The Cave of the Patriachs ( Machpela )in Hebron in Israel is the oldest continuous use building dating back to 40BC . It is a mausoleum used today as a place of prayer . Originally it was built as a cave to bury Abraham’s family . Abraham Isaac and Jacob family are buried there still today . http://en.hebron.org.il/history/669

Comment: The tone of that linked article is rather breathless, and low on facts.  And there are two different structures -- the original natural cave, with likely Bronze Age burials, and the structure built on top of the cave. For more perspectives see https://www.israelhayom.com/2021/11/02/the-secrets-of-the-cave-of-the-patriarchs/ and https://schechter.edu/the-convoluted-history-of-the-cave-of-machpela-in-hebron/

Answer (score 1):

The cathedral in Syracuse was built as a temple to Athena? around 500BCE, and converted into a church around 500CE

Comment: Any links to back this up, especially showing that it is still in use today? Thanks.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral_of_Syracuse) only some columns from the old temple (5th century BC) exist in the current church; the roof is 11th century and the church was rebuilt in a late-baroque style in the 18th century. The OP doesn't explain how much of the building needs to survive.

Answer (score -1):

Il y a la mosquée d'El Aksa à Jérusalem on y pratique à ce jour la prière.

Google translate:
There is the mosque of El Aksa in Jerusalem we practice prayer there to this day.

Comment: Welcome to this site. Note we are an English language site only and all posts need to be in English. (We are happy to help with translations, if asked for.) And only relevant links please, a site about prayers in France or French is not useful here.

Comment: It would help if you could edit this to state when the mosque was built.

Comment: The current mosque dates back to 1035, almost 900 years newer than the Pantheon, and 1400 years newer than the Epidaurus Theater.  Even the original mosque only dates back no further than 634.